# explicit waits in selenium and phantomjs with python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, phantomjs, lxml

I'm trying to scrape some data off of this [site](http://www.cellartracker.com/wine.asp?iWine=901787), and many other "wines" on this site, and am using selenium to do so as its a `JS` site. however, I'm finding that my code only sometimes works and other times it does not return any values even though nothing is changing.

I think I should use explicit waits with `selenium` to overcome this challenge, however I'm not sure how to integrate them, so any guidance on doing so would be helpful!

my code is

```
def ct_content(url):
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    browser.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    html = browser.page_source
    html = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
    try:
        content = html.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "list.asp?Table=List")]/text()')
        browser.quit()
        return content
    except:
        browser.quit()
        return False
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share several links and an element that you want to scrape on all those pages?

Comment: http://www.cellartracker.com/wine.asp?iWine=901787, http://www.cellartracker.com/wine.asp?iWine=709965, http://www.cellartracker.com/wine.asp?iWine=1912334, here are a few of the pages. what I want is '//a[starts-with(@href, "list.asp?Table=List")]/text() which is the table on each page that shows, Vintage, type, producer, Variety, designation, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use more specific `XPath`:

```
//ul[@class="twin_set_list"]//a/text()
```

Also there is no need to use `lxml`. Simply try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

data = [link.get_attribute('textContent') for link in wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//ul[@class="twin_set_list"]//a')))]
```

Comment: the issue with not using waits is that content is only returned sometimes and other times it just returns an empty list for me.

Comment: Did you try above code? no kind of waits can help you to solve the issue as required data is already in initial `HTML` source...

Comment: yeah I tried it, worked first time, second time it returned an empty list

Comment: *second time* == on another page?

Comment: Hmm... This is weird. Ok. Try updated answer with explicitWait applied

Comment: thanks, i tried this, but I get the erro `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: So... at the same page either expected results or `TimeoutException`?

Comment: TimeoutException

Comment: this is exactly what i'm executing                                                          
`def ct_content(url):
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    browser.get(url)
    data = [link.get_attribute('textContent') for link in wait(browser, 
       10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, 
             '//ul[@class="twin_set_list"]//a')))]
   
    print(data)
    return data

     ct_content('http://www.cellartracker.com/wine.asp?iWine=1912334')`

Comment: ran it again, and it worked, so it's not very consistent

Comment: I'd suggest you to avoid using `Phantom` as it's not stable and has a lot of unresolved issues...

Comment: ok, will try and switch to chrome, would this just mean changing everything from  .`PhantomJS() ` to `.Chrome()`

Comment: Just replace `browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()` with `browser = webdriver.Chrome()`. rest of code should remains the same

Comment: ok, so this works pretty consistently, but I think the page has figured out I'm scraping and has begun to ask if I'm human/enter captcha. any suggestions as to bypass this

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue as I get results constantly... try to add few seconds of `time.sleep()` between requests...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never actually use the implicit wait. This is how I would write script with an explicit wait.

```
def ct_content(url):
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    browser.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    try:
        content = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clicable((By.XPATH, '//a[starts-with(@href, "list.asp?Table=List")]')))
        browser.quit()
        return content.text
    except:
        browser.quit()
        return False
```

Also, the way to set implicit waits is:

```
browser.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
```

Comment: It also looks like *you* never use ExplicitWait... Your code is wrong!

Comment: My bad, I changed the non existent driver variable to browser, and added the missing closing paren. Is this any better? If not what's happening?

Comment: @Andersson `content = wait.until(...)` uses the explicit wait, no?

Comment: `content = wait.until(...)` looks like ExplicitWait... Can you tell us what is `xpath()` method and how it should work?